# No commits on dashboard gitlab

Tags: ruby, gitlab

I am using Gitlab using these packages: 
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/GitLab-Debian-packages-%28unofficial%29

It's working all fine, yet I am not seeing commits on my dashboard. Any clue how to fix this?
Unicorn and redis are running fine.

Thijmen

Comment: What version of gitlab are you using? Did you check the logs?

Comment: I am using 4.2.0-1. I checked the logs but nothing really points to an error...

Comment: Did you try with the latest version 5.0pre?

Comment: No, but it should work in 4.2.0-1 if I am right.